How to undo a <history change> push in git?
After a month of working on a personal project, I realized I was using an invalid user.name and user.email so I changed it properly and everything was set right until the last commit done 2 months after. But then I decided that I wanted to change the invalid author name to update my contribution graph for those past commits.
So after reading this answer, I tried:
git rebase -r --root --exec "git commit --amend --no-edit --reset-author"

... to reset the history for the whole project.
But that changed the dates as well. Now I am left with a commit history showing that all the commits of the project were made all at once.
Is there any way to reclaim my old history before resetting it?

git reflog should reveal the commits before your rebase.

Great! Thank you!
